# Translation from "A feast for crows"

Tags: meaning

> No letter will make the Lannisters love us better. Not once they hear that we’ve been helping Stannis.
>   (from *A Feast for Crows*)

I don't understand the sentences above. Does 'not once' mean 'never' or 'frequently'? Could you convert two sentences into one?

Is this correct?
"No letter will make the Lannisters love us better if they hear that we’ve been helping Stannis."

Comment: "once" is equivalent to "when", here.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Yvette. I invite you to visit the [ell.SE] StackExchange site, too, where answers are aimed at the needs of learners. Many people, both askers and answerers, are active on both sites. If you think ELL would be better for this question, click on the *flag* link above and ask that a moderator migrate it.

Answer (score 1):

*Once* is used to speak of an event which you believe has not occurred yet but inevitably will happen in the future.

So a closer paraphrase would be

> No letter will make the Lannisters love us better after they hear that we’ve been helping Stannis.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know what is the difference between 'not once' and 'once'. "~love us better. Not once they hear that~", "~love us better. Once they hear that~".

Comment: Not "when" / "after" they hear that we’ve been helping Stannis.

Comment: @Yvette The *not* is an emphatic repetition of the negative in the preceding clause; in effect it "stands for" that clause, and permits what would otherwise be a subordinate clause to stand on its own. "No letter will make the Lannisters love us better. [*A letter **cannot** make them love us*] once they hear we've been helping Stannis.

Comment: I appreciate your help, StoneyB and Little Eva.